# Specify a range of columns to delete based on duplicate headers

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, multiple-columns

I'm trying to delete duplicate columns (based on column headers) for the first 10 columns of a large spreadsheet.

The following works, but deletes all duplicates. I've tried to modify it to work for the first 10, but have been unsuccessful. Can't seem to figure out how to modify "End(xlToLeft).Column" to = the first 10 columns.

```
Sub Remove_Duplicate_Columns()
Dim lastCols As Long
Dim thisCols As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastCols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For thisCols = lastCols To 2 Step -1
        If Application.Match(.Cells(1, thisCols).Value, Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastCols)), 0) <> thisCols Then
            .Cells(1, thisCols).EntireColumn.Delete xlShiftToLeft
        End If
    Next thisCols
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Isn't it just `lastCols To 10 Step -1` ?

Comment: Yes... 100%.. thank you. I was going crazy. Thank you both!

Comment: I deleted my comment but seeing as I think you actually needed it, `lastCols = 10`...

Comment: Sorry think I got it the wrong way round.